# Java : Getting a value from a properties file

Tags: java, properties, liferay

I'm using the `<liferay-ui:message key="username" />` to get some data from my property file in my portlet.

Is there a Java code equivalent for this tag ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the question title does not go with question content. To read from portlet.properties you have to do as what Jonny said. But on seeing the content of the question, I assume that what you want is the java code equivalent of the tag output that you have mentioned.

liferay-ui:message DOES NOT read the value from portlet.properties file so PortletProps will not work if that is what you are expecting as it is meant to read value only from portlet.properties and not Language.properties.

You should use methods of LanguageUtil class to get the value.

Comment: Good point sandeep, thanks for clarifying that. I've edited my answer to make this point clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's PortletProps.get(String key).

Hope this helps!

~~ EDIT ~~

The above as Sandeep has pointed out isn't the equivalent of what liferay-ui:message does, but it is the method to retrieve values from a portlet.properties file.

As Sandeep has said you should use LanguageUtil to replicate the functionality in Java code.

Answer (score -1):

If you need merely read property from property file you can:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream("file_with.properties"));
String message = p.getProperty("username");
```

Comment: As long as you don't do lines 1 and 2 each time you do a `getProperty`.

Comment: I wouldn't use this method, use Liferay's helper class PortletProps. get() instead of reading through file yourself. But in case of this example you actually want a Language.properties file.